# Rails: Compare current_id value against the average (3 tables)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

so this one has stumped me. I have the following basic model structure;

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :attendances
    has_many :classes, :through => :attendances 

end

class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :student
    validates :student_id, presence: true
    belongs_to :class
    validates :class_id, presence: true

end

class Class < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :attendances
    has_many :students, :through => :attendances    

end
```

I am trying to build a simple app that against a Student (who is the currently logged-in user), we show their average attendance for a given class, plus the average attendance for all students in that class.

The Attendance records simply host the student_id, the class_id and the attendance (currently as an integer).

So a real example would be;

Student attendance in Biology - 80
Average Student attendance in Biology - 96

**What I have tried**

I have tried to define `@students = Student.all` in the Show aspect of the Student controller, and require the params of Attendance and Class, and in my view run `@students.attendance.average('attended')` - {where 'attended' is the column that holds the integer'} - but I get an error that 'attendance' is undefined.

Where am I going wrong on this?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: got the answer from another question and translated into new context...

```
<% class_sums = @student.attendances.group(:class_id).average(:class) %>
<% Class.where(id: class_sums.keys).sort_by {|b| -class_sums[b.id]}.each do |class| %>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><%= class.name %></td>
<td><%= class_sums[class.id] %></td>
<td><%= class.attendances.average(:attended) %></td>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps someone else!